# Reference request for $ \pi_{1}(C,x) $ being generated by $ 2g $ elements for a smooth, connected, curve of genus $ g $

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I believe it is a result of Grothendieck that if $ x $ is a point of a smooth, connected curve $ C $ of genus $ g $ that $ \pi_{1}(C,x) $ is generated by $ 2g $ elements.  Does anyone have a reference for this result?

Comment: This was known long before Grothendieck was born, for example this was known to Riemann.  Any book with "Riemann surfaces" in the tile contains this result.

Comment: Grothendieck proved the corresponding result for the (prime to $p$ part of) étale fundamental group, as a corollary of the topological result. The ref is SGA1.

Comment: As a secondary reference, you may take a look at Milne's Etale Cohomology (PUP, ) page 43, where it is shown that for a smooth projective curve of genus $g$ over an algebraically close field $k$ of characteristic $p$, there is a complete discrete valuation ring $A$ with residue field $k$ and a smooth projective curve $X$ over $A$ such that the original curve is obtained by base-change of $X$, and that for the algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of the field of fractions of the discrete valuation ring $A$,  by the comparison theorem the fundamental group $\pi_1(X_{\overline{K}},\overline{x})$ ...

Comment: ... is the profinite completion of the topological fundamental group of a curve of genus $g$ over ${\mathbb C}$, which is as you mention with a single relation. From there Grothendieck obtained the result mentioned by Donu Arapura.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: Wikipedia thinks that the fundamental group was first defined by Poincaré in 1895, whereas Riemann died in 1866. In any case, your overall point is of course absolutely correct.

Comment: @HJRW: Wikipedia authors did not read Riemann. Yes, Riemann did not define it formally but he used it and he definitely knew its generators.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: interesting! The usual story told in low-dimensional topology is that Poincaré defined the fundamental group in order to prove that his dodecahderal space is not homemorphic to the 3-sphere. Of course, Betti numbers are older and also give the number 2g for a Riemann surface…

Comment: Pretty much every algebraic topology textbook will contain a proof, say, Hatcher or Massey. First, one proves the Seifert-van Kampen theorem.